# three doesn't exist in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js

Some path configuration error i am not able to solve this.
Below is my `package.json` configuration.

```
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/three": "^0.84.35",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.12.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/d3": "^4.12.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"


import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent  {


  @ViewChild('rendererContainer') rendererContainer: ElementRef;
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```

Following is the error i am getting.

```
 /Users/macmini05/Desktop/nieu/src/three doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/macmini05/Desktop/nieu/src/three.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/macmini05/Desktop/nieu/src/three.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              /Users/macmini05/Desktop/nieu/src/three doesn't exist
      looking for modules in /Users/macmini05/Desktop/nieu/src
        using description file: /Users/macmini05/Desktop/nieu/package.json (relative path: ./src)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/macmini05/Desktop/nieu/package.json (relative path: ./src)
          using description file: /Users/macmini05/Desktop/nieu/package.json (relative path: ./src/three)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/macmini05/Desktop/nieu/src/three doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/macmini05/Desktop/nieu/src/three.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your package.json you are missing `three` js. You have only installed `@types/three` which is only typings for `TypeScript`.

You need to install `three` js.

```
npm install three --save
```

Comment: thanks sir , thought that an issue newer version on angular cli